# ansible replaces my double quotes to single quotes which AWS CLI won't accept

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, jinja2, aws-cli

I have this code in a task:

```
shell: aws s3api put-bucket-logging --bucket {{ source_bucket_name }} --bucket-logging-status "{{ lookup("template", "bucket-log-delivery-template.json.j2") }}"
```

Then I have AWS complaining that the parameters need to be surrounded by double quotes. In the output of the ansible run, it shows that everything is single quoted...

I've tried `to_json` filter, which escapes the double quotes which isn't accepted either. I tried different combinations of single and double quotes. No cigar.

Any ideas on what to do? Regex to remove the slashes doesn't work either

Comment: You almost certainly will want `...-logging-status {{ lookup("template", "...") | quote }}` rather than trying to manually double-quote random text produced by the template lookup. That said, since your question didn't bother to include any relevant error message you experienced, the Internet is just left to guess while trying to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Forget Ansible for a minute, and just try echoing the quoted portion of your shell script on the command line:

```
$ echo "{{ lookup("template", "bucket-log-delivery-template.json.j2") }}"
{{ lookup(template, bucket-log-delivery-template.json.j2) }}
```

You'll note that there are *no* quotes in the output, because the quotes are used by the shell to group space-delimited arguments into single tokens. If you want those quotes included in the command line, you need to quote the quotes. One option is just to wrap everything in single quotes:

```
$ echo '"{{ lookup("template", "bucket-log-delivery-template.json.j2") }}"'
"{{ lookup("template", "bucket-log-delivery-template.json.j2") }}"
```

Which would give us the following Ansible task:

```
- shell: aws s3api put-bucket-logging --bucket {{ source_bucket_name }} --bucket-logging-status '"{{ lookup("template", "bucket-log-delivery-template.json.j2") }}"'
```

You can make that a lot easier to read like this:

```
- shell: >-
    aws s3api put-bucket-logging
    --bucket {{ source_bucket_name }}
    --bucket-logging-status
    '"{{ lookup("template", "bucket-log-delivery-template.json.j2") }}"'
```